# How do I bind .animate() on parent tag to its child tag?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

so I've been trying to build a reactive website, where I've parent tag <form> which changes its size and opacity when hovered. However, inside that form tag I have <input /> tag which should ideally not interrupt with the animation on form tag while mouse hovers on <input />. But, somehow it breaks my animation and I've been struggling with it for a while.

**CSS:**

```
/* Block 1 starts */

#block-1{
    background-image: url("/HealthCare/images/block-1.png");
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 10px 10px 10px #000000;
    text-shadow: 50px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 5%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Bform-1 starts */



/* Bform-1 Name ends */
article > section > form{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: initial;
}
#bform-input-1{
    width: 250px;
    height: 25px;
    overflow: initial;
}

/* Block 1 ends */

/* Block 2 start */
#block-2{
    background-image: url("/HealthCare/images/block-2.png");
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    display: flex;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-style: oblique;
    font-size: 10px 10px 10px #000000;
    text-shadow: 50px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 5%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    text-align: center;
}
/* Block 2 ends */


/* Block 3 start */
#block-3{
    background-image: url("/HealthCare/images/block-3.png");
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 5%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    text-align: center;
}
/* Block 2 ends */
```

**JS and JQuery**

```
 // Block-1 Animation Code.
    $('#block-1').on("mouseover",function(){
        $('#block-1').animate({
            'height':'450px',
            'width':'450px',
            opacity:1
        },100,'linear');
    });
    $('#block-1').on("mouseout",function(){
        $('#block-1').animate({
            'height':'400px',
            'width':'400px',
            opacity:0.8
        },100,'linear');
    });

    // Block-2 Animation Code.
    $('#block-2').on("mouseover",function(){
        $('#block-2').animate({
            'height':'450px',
            'width':'450px',
            opacity:1
        },100,'linear');
    });
    $('#block-2').on("mouseout",function(){
        $('#block-2').animate({
            'height':'400px',
            'width':'400px',
            opacity:0.8
        },100,'linear');
    });

    // Block-3 Animation Code.
    $('#block-3').on("mouseover",function(){
        $('#block-3').animate({
            'height':'450px',
            'width':'450px',
            opacity:1
        },100,'linear');
    });
    $('#block-3').on("mouseout",function(){
        $('#block-3').animate({
            'height':'400px',
            'width':'400px',
            opacity:0.8
        },100,'linear');
    });
});
```

**Html**

```
<main>
            <article id="important_inf_blocks">
                <section id="block-1">
                    <form>
                        <input id="bform-input-1" type="text" />
                    </form>
                </section>
                <section id="block-2">
                    block-2
                </section>
                <section id="block-3">
                    block-3
                </section>
            </article>
</main>
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong. Can you describe more what the problem is - I just see the form scaling up/down and the input within it doing the same. Perhaps you could create a runnable snippet so we can see the problem for ourselves. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi I've solved the problem, thank you so much for your reply. I solved the problem by stopping animation through each iteration, by adding ` .stop() ` before ` .animate() ` so that it won't affect the scaling or make it flicker.  However, I will still make a working snippet with previous, and new code so that the community would be able to see through it and understand what the problem was for future similar encounters. Thank you.